# check if data exists before insert and return true/false?

Tags: mysql, insert

**Solution:**

Place unique constraint on multiple columns

```
ALTER TABLE rating ADD UNIQUE KEY ( id , id );
```

---

I want to insert a score in my rating system. I want to be able to insert data if it doesn't exist. I also want the same query to return true/false if it **does** exist.

I looked into `INSERT IGNORE` but that silently fails so I don't know how to check against that.

I know I could attempt a `SELECT ... WHERE id = 1` and THAN do the insert, but I want to move this down to a single insert, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a unique key constraint on the column or columns you want to check against, then a normal insert will succeed if there is no data already, or fail noisily due to unique key constraint if there is already something matching.

Comment: I know of this, but I am afraid, due to the database structure, using a unique constraint is not an option.

Comment: Then you need to fix the database structure...badly designed databases lead to complicated controls which will one day go wrong.

Comment: it is not poorly designed... don't know why you would assume that.

Comment: actually, I took your idea and placed in two columns; something I didn't know I could do...

Comment: happy days, please explain why key constraints is not appropriate - I am interested to know

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `rating` (value1) 
SELECT 'your rate for  value1' FROM `rating` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `rating` 
WHERE value1='your rate for  value1' ) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: do you know what this would return on a query where the data existed?